# how to encrypt a dual booted Ubuntu and win7 system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

I am very new to Linux and I wanted to encrypt my newly installed Ubuntu system. Only issue is that I have a dual booted system with Win7, and when I tried to install the Ubuntu alongside with win7 it would not give me the option for encryption unless I wiped my existing windows partition. Is there a way to encrypt both partitions together after both have install, and still to use the GRUB to switch between the OS's on boot??

Answer (score 0):

If your windows 7 running with Enterprise/Ultimate you can use Bitlocker to encrpyt it and for Ubuntu you can use LUKS,